# Objects in mirror are losing meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of `objects in mirror are losing` phrase?

Does it mean that the driver which is reading the phrase on the wing mirror will see all the cars behind him and if it were the speed race those car behind would lose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning "objects in mirror are closer than they appear" is well established. Subverting a common phrase with a surprise ending is a standard humorous construction, and yes, the analogy is to a car race. Overall there's not really any more to it than you've seen already.

Comment: Google mobile is refusing to allow a search by date, but I'd like to dig more into the history